Generic packages for assembly tests
I'm thinking of getting a pick and place machine, however I need to test the capabilities of the thing, to make sure it actually performs properly for the given task.
The idea I have is to send some boards and components to the pnp manufacturer so they can run some tests in there, however, some of the components are not precisely cheap, so I'm wondering whether it's possible to get "blank components" meaning, some device that actually does nothing, or allows you to do some conductivity test, but has the right footprint and a low cost.
The first question is, does anyone know if something like this even exist?
And 2: if so, anyone knows where to source something like this?

economy of scale suggest that test-specific components might still be more expensive than the actual devices. That's not going to be the case for 10k€ FPGAs, but my guess is that you will find some end-of-life large BGA components if that's what you're after.

Yes, it does exist. I haven't used it myself but a collogue of mine used to work for a company making cell phones and due to time-to-market and Christmas sales being very important, they ordered empty BGA capsules to have the soldering process and rest of manufacturing tuned and ready to go as soon as the final PCB and ASICs were ready. Smaller stuff like resistors and capacitors they used standard ones, but could normally ignore the value on them and just used the correct capsule. He showed lots of very shiny phones with zero functionality but of great use to start testing electromechanical integration, feel on buttons, production time, screw torque, shock and vibration, optimizing pick-and-place, wear tests on charger and headphone (this was a few years ago) jacks and the like.
Your second question is off topic here and I don't have the answer anyway.
